# Como fazer um insert no mysql com dados vindos de um SimpleDataSet

Tags: mysql, delphi, firebird

Tenho um **SimpleDataset** com dados de um *Firebird* local.

Eu tenho que fazer um `Insert` no *Mysql*.

Como devo fazer isso?

Outro **SqlConnect** e outro **SimpleDataSet**?

Como fazer o *insert* com dados desse outro **SimpleDataSet**(**firebird**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei como funciona este componente, mas no geral você faz um laço no `DataSet` fazendo `insert` de cada item dele!

Funciona como se fosse um importador!

Ex:

```
NomeDataSet.First
while not NomeDataSet.Eof do
begin
  //aqui seu Código SQL para efetuar o Insert
  NomeDataSet.Next
end;
```

E Sim, você precisara das duas conexões!

Ali onde esta comentado você executa a `query` que efetuara o `insert` no 2º SqlConnect (conexão do MySql).

Comment: Mas o insert eu coloquei no sql command. Gostaria de passar os dados de um para o outro. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Fiz uma edição enquanto seu comentário era inserido, da uma olhada!

Comment: Algo desse tipo?

`'insert interditado values ( (SELECT u.id as id_usuario FROM serventia s, usuarios u
      where u.serventia_id = s.id) as USUARIO_ID , SimpleDataSetNOME_PAI , SimpleDataSetMAE,
      sysdate(), SimpleDataSetCPFCNPJ );`'

Comment: Exato, o comando fica a seu critério.